# Query, Cell Reference, Wildcard Characters

Tags: regex, filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to refer to a cell reference within a *Google Sheets Query* where the cell reference contains wild card characters or characters such as `<, >`, and if can you tell me what syntax to use?

I've attempted to perform the query using the following syntax:

```
=query(A1:A6, "select A where A='"&H1&"'")
```

where the values are as follows:

```
A       
--
as    
as    
bs
```

If H1 set to `as`, then rows 1 and 2 are returned.

If H1 set to `?s`, then `'Empty Ouput'` is returned

If a similar query is undertaken but using data containing numeric values, and with `<, >` in H1, again the query returns `'Empty Output'`, i.e.

```
=query(B1:B6, "select B where B contains '"&H1&"'")
```

Where B contains numeric values and H1 is set to `>0`

I've also tried using *Filter* but I can't get that to work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use wildcards, you can use the [Like operator](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/like-string-operator-in-google-sheets-query/):

```
=query(A1:A6, "select A where A like '"&H1&"'")
```

with _s in H1.

To do the same with numeric selections, you can build the select statement like this:

```
=query(B1:B6, "select B where B"&I1)
```

with >0 in I1.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can also use regex in `FILTER` like:

```
=FILTER(A1:A6, REGEXMATCH(A1:A6, ".*"&H1))
```

where **H1**: **`s`**

Comment: Thank you - both answers very helpful but this is a little bit more straightforward, thanks for the replies